# Temporary directory persist across program runs

Tags: python, tempdata, tempdir

I need a temporary directory, but I want full control over its creation and deletion.

I will use this directory to place git repositories which I want to monitor for new commits, so I need to store them somewhere permanently.

Therefore I want to avoid `/tmp` dir, since it can be cleared by user(?). What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/platformdirs is a Python package that offers a cross-platform `user_cache_dir` function.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I guess this is the way to go. I'm just wondering `user_cache_dir` vs `site_data_dir`, which is more suitable for my case.

Comment: It seems appdirs has been deprecated. Enter [platformdirs](https://github.com/platformdirs/platformdirs).

Answer (score 8):

[`tempfile.mkdtemp`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) will create a temp dir for you and return its name. It will create it in `/tmp` by default (on Unix-like systems), but "in the most secure manner possible" and with read/write/list permissions only for the caller's user id.

```
>>> d = tempfile.mktemp()
>>> with open(os.path.join(d, "secret")) as output:
...     output.write("Ha, you can't read this!")
```

(Btw., on a Unix/Linux system with default settings, users can't just edit or remove each others' files from `/tmp`.)

Comment: Hehum, I was looking at this. So, I can't rely that once created tempdir will always be there? Also, I need to remember once created dir path and use it on every app run, right? Do you recommend creating one top level tmpdir for all my subdirs (git repos) or to separate each in it's own tempdir? Thanks.

Comment: @umpirsky: do you want the temp dir to persist across program runs?

Comment: This will most likely just create a directory in `/tmp` which is the default for [`tempfile.tempdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir).

Comment: Maybe I put my question wrong, sorry. I prefer to persist data accross program runs, and computer reboots if possible. So it would be better to put it somewhere inside app install dir `os.path.dirname(__file__), '../data/cache')`.

Comment: @umpirsky: that would require write access to the installation dir. Why not put it in the user's home dir? `os.getenv("HOME")`.

Comment: @larsmans You are right, permissions. Hehum, will HOME var be always defined? I would like to somehow hide this caching from app users.

Comment: @umpirsky: `HOME` is practically always defined. If it's not, the user's setup is so broken that you should just kill the program.

Comment: Windows and MacOSX as well? Where do you recommend to put is inside HOME?

Comment: @umpirsky: on Mac OS X yes, not sure about Windows.

Comment: not in CPython standard lib. Third-party toolkits that are more desktop-oriented, like QT, have their own cross-platform functions to find the right directory. See my answer below for the best approach in a pure-python world.

Comment: "will HOME var be always defined?" in the Nix sandbox, HOME is defined as /homeless-shelter but does not exist. mkdir $HOME throws permission denied. so you could try [xdg.xdg_cache_home()](https://pypi.org/project/xdg/) and fallback to /tmp

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that the best practice is to use [`tempfile.mkdtemp`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp).

If you don't wan to use `/tmp` then, you can take advantage of the `prefix` parameter:

```
import tempfile
tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=<your_preferred_directory>)
```

Edit: Regarding what's the most appropriate directory to sotre your application configuration, cache data, etc. If you're using linux, please have a look at the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Answer (score 2):

If it's really temporary, follow larmans' advice and use `mkdtemp`.

If it's some sort of semi-permanent cache that must survive reboots, then you should use the local application directory, as defined by your OS (%APPDATA%, ~/.local/ etc); some toolkits (e.g. Qt) provide functions to look that folder up in a cross-platform manner.

Edit: from Wikipedia:

- HOME (Unix-like) and USERPROFILE (Microsoft Windows) - indicate where
  a user's home directory is located in the file system.
- HOME/{.AppName} (Unix-like) and APPDATA{DeveloperName\AppName}
  (Microsoft Windows) - for storing application settings. Many open
  source programs incorrectly use USERPROFILE for application settings
  in Windows - USERPROFILE should only be used in dialogs that allow
  user to choose between paths like Documents/Pictures/Downloads/Music,
  **for programmatic purposes use APPDATA (roaming), LOCALAPPDATA or
  PROGRAMDATA (shared between users)**

So you should look up `os.environ['APPDATA']` or `os.environ['HOME']`, depending on platform (see `sys.platform`) and then append your app name, and then you can store there anything you want.

```
mydir = os.path.join( ".myAppName", "cache")
homeVar = 'HOME'  # default for all *nix variants
if sys.platform == 'win32': 
   homeVar = 'APPDATA'
mydir = os.path.join( os.environ[homeVar], mydir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually programs use a `~/.progname` directory to store data that should be persistent but should stay "out of the way" of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Just a though: You may want to look into git [commit hooks](http://bit.ly/wDgniE). That way, instead of monitoring a tmp directory for new commits (sounds strange: who would commit into a tmp directory with limited permissions?) the repo informs you about commits, or, more specifically, automatically runs a script whenever a commit occurs..

Comment: I am building some kind of git monitor, which will notify about changes in master branch. Sth like githubs RSS feed. In order to detect changes, I need to fetch repo somewhere. That's why I need tmp dir. Thx,

Comment: Wouldn't you want to have it in a permanent directory then, so you don't have to clone the entire repo every time you want to check for changes?